# Migration from Tomcat 6.0 to JBoss AS 6.0

Tags: tomcat, jboss, webserver, migration

What is the main difference between Tomcat 6.0 and JBoss 6.0?
We have developed three products of webapps under Tomcat 6.0 which runs on Linux in production server.
We have decided to migrate the three products of webapps from Tomcat 6.0 to JBoss 6.0. What are the main steps to follow to migrate from previous(tomcat) to current (jboss).

What are the steps am I to follow the migration ?

Answer (score 2):

We're 3 years older and JBoss AS 6 was obsolted by JBoss AS 7 and WildFly 8.
So I assume today's readers want to migrate to that.

There are two tools which help with migration to JBoss AS 7 / WildFly 8 / EAP 6:

1) [JBoss SwanLoom](https://github.com/OndraZizka/jboss-migration/wiki/) - automated migration tool aimed to server configuration migration.

2) [JBoss WindUp](http://windup.jboss.org/) - a reporting tool aimed to application migration - deployment descriptors etc.

And finally, there's a new site dedicated to JBoss migration: http://www.jboss.org/migration/ , where you can find all the migration guides to do the migration manually.

Answer (score 0):

re 1) Tomcat is a servlet container while JBoss AS is a Java EE container (that also supports EJBs)

Comment: Thanks for ur reply.Sorry ,i think you aren't understand my problem.I don't need the main difference of that.I need how to migrate from tomcat 6.0 to jboss 6.0 ?