# migration from Jboss to Tomcat?

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, jboss

What is the main difference between Tomcat 6.0 and JBoss 6.0?
We have developed a product of webapps under JBoss 6.0 ,
We have decided to migrate the our products of webapps from  JBoss 6.0 Tomcat 6.0 to What are the main steps to follow to migrate from current (jboss) previous(tomcat) to .

What are the steps am I to follow the migration ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4266963/migration-from-tomcat-6-0-to-jboss-as-6-0

Answer (score 0):

If you use Java EE (EJB, JMS and others), you will need an application server like JBoss or Glassfish, Tomcat simply doesn't support these technologies. If not, it should be piece of cake, so just try it and ask here if you encounter any issues.